# Countifs formula with criteria value in array

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have a list of accounts and am creating a countifs formula with multiple variables, based on a changelog in a separate sheet.

Currently it stands like this (please note the values in quotation marks are distinct TEXT values as they are system codes and not numeric value):

```
=COUNTIFS(Changelog!$A$1:$A$1000,A1,Changelog!$L$1:$L$1000,"=3",Changelog!G$1:G$1000,{"=993","=Z94","=Z95","=Z96","=Z97","=998","=999"})
```

As you can notice there are 3 types of variables that create the criteria.
First 2 are rather self explanatory: 1st we have a search in changelog for the account in the A1 cell (so we will have a list of changes on each account), 2nd is a search for those whose respective L cell value equals to 3.

So far so good. However the problem arises for me with including the third condition. I want to check whether the account has one of the values in a G column. The formula works only for the first value (that being "993").

For example, If in the changelog there is a line in which in column A value is equal to the account number, column L will have the value of "3" and in column G there is a value of "993", than the count will show "1". If however the G column has a value of (for example) "Z95", than the formula shows 0.

I wonder how it can be done to implement such a "logical OR" criteria that would take any of the values into account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Tested**

```
=SUM(COUNTIFS(Changelog!$A$1:$A$1000,A1,Changelog!$L$1:$L$1000,"=3",Changelog!G$1:G$1000,{"993","Z94","Z95","Z96","Z97","998","999"}))
```

**Add Sum in Front**

Remove = Sign

Comment: The values are text. They are distinct values as they are codes, not values. My bad on not clarifying that. Corrected in the main text.

Comment: Yeah I understand that. Is this not working ? I think it should work even if they are Text

Comment: Well no as it is supposed to take not only the numeric values but also some which are pure text. In the example I did not input all of them, updated as well to underline the issue.

Comment: BIimey now it did.

Thank you kindly good sir.

The solution is so simple that I feel like a complete dummy now. :-)

Comment: Removing `=` made no difference to me. Both worked. :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an example on how you can approach this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Changelog!A1:A1000=A1)*(Changelog!G1:G1000={"993","Z94","Z95","Z96","Z97","998","999"})*(Changelog!L1:L1000="3"))
```

Comment: Please reread the query as the values are text, not numeric. thus it does not have a value that can be treated mathematically. I have corrected the question as it may have been misleading. Thank you for your effort nontheless.

Comment: @MarcinKonopka, yes i noticed through the comments. It's clear now after your update. Answer edited accordingly.